# Unity3D как сделать ограничение по нажатию клавиши?

Tags: unity3d

как сделать ограничение по нажатию клавиши в Unity 3D например пробел только 1 раз в секунду?
версия 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю, таких задержек у тебя в игре много. Напиши класс Cooldown, в котором у тебя есть корутина, запрещающая сделать что либо на определённое время, а потом снимающая запрет.
Имею ввиду что-то подобное:

```
public class Cooldown : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float cooldownTime { get; set; }
    public bool canDoAction{ get; set; }
    public void StartTimer() => StartCoroutine(ICooldown());
    private void Start()
    {
        canDoAction = true;
    }
    private IEnumerator ICooldown()
    {
        canDoAction = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(cooldownTime);
        canDoAction = true;
    }
}
```

В нужном классе создаёшь экземпляр класса Cooldown, при этом в проверку нажатия на кнопку добавляешь условие что бы canDoAction было true.
Как-то так:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private Cooldown _shootCooldown;
..... some variables, methods.
private void Update()
{
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z) && _shootCooldown.canDoAction)
{
Shoot();
_shootCooldown.StartTimer();
}

}

}
```

Такая система довольно гибкая, тебе не придётся писать кучу лишних корутин в каждый класс, вместо этого ты просто создаёшь новый экземпляр класса Cooldown и добавляешь проверку. Главное не забудь скрипт Cooldown повесить на нужный объект.

Comment: а "..... some variables, methods." можно ведь удалить?

Comment: ну да, это не часть кода

Comment: у меня что то не так все равно вот код        using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cooldown : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Cooldown _shootCooldown;
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown('space')_shootCooldown.canDoAction)
        {
            Shoot();
            _shootCooldown.StartTimer();
        }

    }

}

Comment: между методом инпута и проверкой canDoAction поставь &&

Comment: опять ругается                       using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cooldown : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Cooldown && _shootCooldown;
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown('space')_shootCooldown.canDoAction)
        {
            Shoot();
            _shootCooldown.StartTimer();
        }

    }

} ошибка: Assets\��࠭�祭������릪��.cs(10,65): error CS1513: } expected

Comment: Не в том месте прописан &&. Правильнее вот тут: 

if (Input.GetKeyDown('space') **&&**_shootCooldown.canDoAction)

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое это что то типа такого

```
bool spacePressed;
float spaceTimer;
void Update() {
    if (spacePressed) {
        spaceTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (spaceTimer >= 1) {
            spacePressed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

И если spacePressed == true, то не давать прыгать

Ну и после прыжка обнулять таймер

Comment: Это тип полный код? Напиши плз прям полный

Comment: такой код очень сложно поддерживать, потому-что у тебя будет куча проверок, сложений чисел в апдейте, а сделать с этим ничего не получится.

Comment: да, вы правы, но в виде алгоритма и идеи может существовать спокойно.